# Can I use a MySQL PREPARE statement in a function to create a query with a variable table name

Tags: mysql

I want to create a function that has a select query inside that can be used against multiple database tables but I can not use a variable as the table name. Can I get around this using a PREPARE statement in the function?

An Example:

```
FUNCTION `TESTFUNC`(dbTable VARCHAR(25)) RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN

    DECLARE datereg DATETIME;
    DECLARE stmt VARCHAR(255);

    SET stmt := concat(
      'SELECT dateT FROM', dbTable, 'ORDER BY dateT DESC LIMIT 1');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;

    EXECUTE stmt;

    RETURN dateT;

END $$
```

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Yes, you can,  it's often used, but in a lot of cases should be avoided, and considering the elaborate example you posted I'm surprised you didn't take the one step further in testing it, which would have given you the answer straight away.

Comment: I did test it and it did not work, hence the question.

Comment: @Wrikken: Yes it doesn't work because it's in a function. You would receive `ERROR 1336 (0A000): Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger` when creating this function.

Comment: Ah, damn, function / SP difference got to me, I apologize. On a side note: I'd add some spaces surrounding the tablename in that example...

Comment: No problem I got it working so thanks to everyone.

Comment: How did you get it to work in a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `stmt varchar(255)` use @stmt:

```
...
 DECLARE datereg DATETIME;
  SET @stmt = concat(
  'SELECT dateT FROM', dbTable, 'ORDER BY dateT DESC LIMIT 1');
  ....
```

Comment: This does indeed appear to work but only in a Stored Procedure which does not help for what I was trying to because I wanted to use it in a function or a trigger.

Comment: Yes, it works in SP only. @Wrikken mentioned it in his comment to your question. Personally I missed the point that you use FUNCTION, not SP...